# osm2pgsql error Trying to import .osm to postGis on Ubuntu Server

Tags: postgis

I am trying to set up a tile server on Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I have installed Postgresql and PostGis and Mapnik and Osm2pgsql. I am trying to run the following command to import the maps of Northern Ireland into the gis database. 
osm2pgsql --slim -d gis -W -S -C 800 ireland-and-northern-ireland.osm.pbf

And then when I hit enter I get prompted to enter my password then I get the following what I assume is an error

Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Couldn't open style file '-C': No such file or directory
Error occurred, cleaning up
 I do not understand what is going on and how to get the osm file into the database all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not at my pc right now, but just by looking at the errormsg and your cmdline, i'd say that the -S option should be followed by the path of a style file. Does it work when you omit the -S option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> -S|--style 
>   Location     of     the     style     file.      Default      to /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style

It tries to open the argument '-C' as file. If the file '/usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style' is available on your tileserver you can omit the -S option.

Comment: The reason I entered the -S is because I kept getting an error about the default.style not being found, I guess the osm2pgsql install uses a path of /usr/share/default.style instead of /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style so I found on the Ubuntu osm2pgsql instruction page to use the -S to stop the error I was getting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just want to start off saying thank you to everyone who responded to my question. I had made a big mistake as I was trying resolved the question and I download to many maps at once and filled my hard drive and do matter how I tried to do a restore in Ubuntu I could not. So I completely deleted the entire Ubuntu Server and the tile server I had set up. I re-installed Ubuntu, I followed the tutorial at http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/ and went through my steps to set up a tile server and found that when I had setup Mapnik-Styles I had not changed estimate_extent to false and “extent” to “20037508,-19929239,20037508,19929239″ in the datasource-settings.xml.inc file. After I rechecked all of my steps everything started to work fine. So again thanks for all of the help.